# Noob: How to put python on the debian system path?

Tags: debian

I'm proud to have rented my own debian 6.0 server. And as a total noob in Linux (probably it is not the best thing to learn debian with a webserver first...i know!) I want to deploy python django apps with this server.

**Now the simple command "python" is not working.**

when I'm looking for installations with

> whereis python

it shows me the following Information:

> python: /usr/lib/python2.5 /usr/lib/python2.4 /usr/lib/python2.6
>   /usr/lib64/python2.5 /usr/lib64/python2.4 /usr/lib64/python2.6

so python is present on the system?!...but how to put python2.6 on the system path so that "python" is working and opens the python shell?

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is actually to learn about Debian/Linux and the tools you want to use.

Comment: This is NOT a Python question.  It's a Debian question.  It probably belongs on superuser.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python2.6 and do this:

```
# apt-get install python2.6
```

**Edit:** And if you realy want `python` call `python2.6` use

```
# update-alternatives --config python
```

Comment: You can install multiple versions of Python at the same time. But only one of them can be called `python`. Use `update-alternatives`.

Comment: On how to set alternative python versions: http://www.stylesen.org/python_27_debian_squeeze_60